# How to create own block helper with two or more nested children?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I'd like to to something nested like that in my views:

```
<%= helper_a do |ha| %>
  Content for a
  <%= ha.helper_b do |hb| %>
    Content for b
    <%= hb.helper_c do |hc| %>
      Content for c
      ... and so on ...
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

To get for example this:

```
<tag_a>
  Content for a
  <tag_b class="child_of_tag_a">
    Content for b
    <tag_c class="nested_child_of_tag_a child_of_tag_b">
      Content for c
    </tag_c>
  </tag_b>
</tag_a>
```

This means, each level has access to some information of the level above (that's why they are nested and not completely autonomous methods)

I know how to create a simple helper:

```
def helper_a(&block)
  content = capture(&block)
  content_tag :tag_a, content
end
```

And I know I can pass my arguments to the `capture` to use them in the view, so something like this to get live up the `|ha|` of my example

```
def helper_a(&block)
  content = capture(OBJECT_HERE, &block)
  content_tag :tag_a, content
end
```

But where do I define this `OBJECT_HERE`, especially the class for it, and how can this go on nested with multiple levels capturing each block?

Comment: Do you really need to put the nesting information in html classes? From your example, I wouldn't bother with it and use "tag_a tag_b { property: value }" in CSS or "$('tag_a tag_b')" in jQuery. Could you tell if you need to do something other than CSS styling and/or Javascript manipulation?

Comment: The extra classes added are just for the example here, with that you're right. It might be some other things that change depending on the "nested information". But it looks like I'm trying to do it too complicated anyway if I need more than one nested level, so I should think about my application design.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came up with a couple solutions, but I'm far from being an expert in the Rails templating system.

The first one is using an instance variable :

```
def helper_a(&block)
  with_context(:tag_a) do
    content = capture(&block)
    content_tag :tag_a, content
  end
end

def helper_b(&block)
  with_context(:tag_b) do
    content = capture(&block)
    content_tag :tag_b, content
  end
end

def helper_c(&block)
  with_context(:tag_c) do
    content = capture(&block)
    content_tag :tag_c, content
  end
end

def with_context(name)
  @context ||= []
  @context.push(name)
  content = yield
  @context.pop
  content
end
```

which is used this way :

```
<%= helper_a do %>
  Content for a
  <%= helper_b do %>
    Content for b
    <%= helper_c do %>
      Content for c
      ... and so on ...
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

And the other solution, which passes the context at each step :

```
def helper_a(context = [], &block)
  context = capture(context.push(:tag_a), &block)
  content_tag(:tag_a, content)
end

def helper_b(context = [], &block)
  context = capture(context.push(:tag_b), &block)
  content_tag(:tag_b, content)
end

def helper_c(context = [], &block)
  context = capture(context.push(:tag_c), &block)
  content_tag(:tag_c, content)
end
```

which is used this way :

```
<%= helper_a do |context| %>
  Content for a
  <%= helper_b(context) do |context| %>
    Content for b
    <%= helper_c(context) do |context| %>
      Content for c
      ... and so on ...
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

But I'd really advise against using either of these solutions if all you're doing is CSS styling and/or Javascript manipulation. It really complicates the helpers, is likely to introduce bugs, etc.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, this look like two ways how to do it. Just thought of a similar solution with instance variables some hours ago. And came to the conclusion to think about why my application design needs so many nested levels and to do something against that rather than trying to nest like hell ;-) But if I still have to, I'll use one of these.

Comment: I do the same thing all the time, banging my head against an overengineered solution because I had something in mind, and then stepping back and telling myself "doh, I don't need all this crap" ;-)